# Alternate for Whey!

Tags: diet, protein, high-protein

I'm tring to get all the nutritions from natural food. But I cannot find a alternate for Whey. I'm using cottage cheese instead of Cesain supplements, which is a low digesting protein. Eggs as medium digesting protein. But I cannot find any fast digesting protein, easy availble food as an alterante to whey supplements. So which is best fast digesting protein rich natural food?

Comment: Whey protein powder *is* a natural food.

Comment: just because it is powdered does not mean it is bad, you also assume that anything "unnatural" is bad which is a fallacy to nature.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the name `whey` suggests, you could maybe go to your local farmer and get some fresh whey.

If this does not suit you, you could try to get some natural whey powder. I do not mean the `unflavoured whey protein`, but the really natural whey.

If you still do not want the powder, you could simply drink milk. It also has a decent amount of whey protein by nature....

There does not seem to be a real alternative besides that. I dug through some posts on  the internet now and some suggest egg whites, but I think the best would be a whey shake.

The benefit of a shake in general is the better and faster digestability, so maybe you should really consider it.

Answer (score 2):

Nuts and soy products are a great source of fast non-dairy protein. (You can generally find a soy isolate protein powder in a nutrition store).

Personally I'm a big fan of peanut butter and almonds. Just watch your fat intake with adding nuts to your diet.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend quaker with milk,yogurt,banana (general fruits).I haven't take never whey. I can't say whey if it gains more but like those it can replace.I hope to help